# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Response has unsuccessful status

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, sms, ringcentral

I am trying to send SMS through RingCentral. This is the error I am getting below.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Response has unsuccessful status in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(276): RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(363): RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->sendRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(183): RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->requestToken('/restapi/oauth/...', Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/includes/ring-central.class.php(26): RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->login(Array, '#Gc090486', '101') #4 /Applicati in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Paradise/wp-content/plugins/ring-central/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php on line 50

```
<?php

use RingCentral\SDK\SDK;

define("FAILED", 1);
define("LOCKED", 2);

class RingCentralConnection {

private $_sdk;

private $_platform;

function __construct($clientId, $secret) {

}

//https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/159048008/extension/171857008/call-log?dateFrom=2012-08-26

public function sendSMS($from, $to, $text) {
    $_credentials = require (getPluginDir().'/includes/credentials.php');
    $_sdk         = new SDK($_credentials['appKey'], $_credentials['appSecret'], $_credentials['server'], '2FA Demo', '1.0.0');
    //print_r($_sdk);
    $_platform = $_sdk->platform();


    try {
        $_platform->login($_credentials['username'], $_credentials['extension'], $_credentials['password']);
        // $code     = generateRandomCode(6);
        // $myNumber = $_credentials['username'];
        // try {
        //  $response = $_platform->post('/account/~/extension/~/sms', array(
        //          'from' => array('phoneNumber' => $myNumber),
        //          'to'   => array(array('phoneNumber'   => $to)),
        //          'text' => $message
        //      ));

        //  $status = $response->json()->messageStatus;
        //  echo $status;
        //  if ($status == "SendingFailed" || $status == "DeliveryFailed") {
        //      //$db->close();
        //      createResponse(new Response(FAILED, "RC server connection error. Please try again."));
        //  } else {
        //      //$timeStamp = time();
        //      //$query = "UPDATE users SET code= " . $code . ", codeexpiry= " . $timeStamp . " WHERE email='" . $email . "'";
        //      //$db->query($query);
        //      //$db->close();
        //      createResponse(new Response(LOCKED, $message));
        //  }
        // } catch (ApiException $e) {
        //  //$db->close();
        //  $this->createResponse(new Response(FAILED, "RC server connection error. Please try again in."));
        // }
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        //$db->close();
        //print_r($e);
        $this->createResponse(new Response(FAILED, "RC server connection error. Please try again out."));
    }

}

function createResponse($res) {
    $response = json_encode($res);
    echo $response;
}
function databaseError() {
    $res      = new Response(UNKNOWN, "Unknown database error. Please try again.");
    $response = json_encode($res);
    die($response);
}
}
class Response {
    function __construct($error, $message) {
        $this->error   = $error;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public $error;
    public $message;
}

//credentials
return array(
    'username'  => '+13128589951',
    'extension' => '101', // extension number
    'password'  => '',
    'appKey'    => '',
    'appSecret' => '',
    'server'    => 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com'// for production - https://platform.ringcentral.com
);
```

Comment: What happens if you debug your code?

Comment: Debug further and the issue is cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 405 from proxy after CONNECT. It might auth but all credentials are correct.

Comment: Since you are using the password flow grant, it's worth checking if your credentials are correct. Can you successfully use your username/extension/password to login to the Sandbox Online Account Portal ( https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com ) or retrieve an access token using the following curl command: `curl -u '{clientId}:{clientSecret}' -d 'grant_type=password&username={username}&extension={extension}&password={password}' -X POST https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ran the cmd line and I got

Comment: curl -u '1{clientId}:{clientSevret}' -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&username=+13128589951&extension=101&password={password}' -X POST https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Parameter [code] value is invalid",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "CMN-101",
    "message" : "Parameter [code] value is invalid",
    "parameters" : [ {
      "parameterName" : "parameterName",
      "parameterValue" : "code"
    } ]
  } ]
}

Comment: {
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Parameter [code] value is invalid",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "CMN-101",
    "message" : "Parameter [code] value is invalid",
    "parameters" : [ {
      "parameterName" : "parameterName",
      "parameterValue" : "code"
    } ]
  } ]
}

Comment: grant_type should be password instead of authorization_code

Comment: It did work either. For platform type for php doy set it to web/server.